# Curl Delete function dumps JSON to browser - how to fix

Tags: rest, codeigniter, curl

The following function transfers a curl delete request to an API, and returns the response to PHP.

The API returns a JSON array for all requests (get, post, put and delete), and everything works fine for everything except delete requests.

The following curl function doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
function curl_delete($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $result; // <-- Function ALWAYS returns whether this is here or not??!..
}
```

This is how I call the function from PHP:

```
// [DELETE API URL]:
$url = 'http://localhost/website/api/users/user/id/123';

$html = json_decode(curl_delete($url), true);
```

If you look at the function (above), whether or not I include the return statement (at the end of the function), the result of the curl call (the jsonified array) always gets dumped to the browser after the function has completed - which is not what I want.

If I then say `echo count($html)`, the correct length of the returned result will print, and the `$html` array is working fine, however I can't seem to prevent it from automatically dumping to the screen.

This does not happen for any of the other curl functions, which just work as expected.

QUESTION:

Is this normal behaviour?  How do I prevent the json from dumping to the screen?

PS Using Codeigniter & Phil Sturgeon's REST Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Phil Sturgeon's cURL library for Codeigniter](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl) and its method `simple_delete()` :

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$url = 'http://localhost/website/api/users/user/id/123';
$response = $this->curl->simple_delete($url);
$html = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

If it does not solve your problem, maybe you will have to take a closer look at your REST server.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but adding the code :-

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

resolved it